# Equivalence Relations of n|(x1-x2)

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

How would one prove that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, then $x_1$ ~ $x_2$ <=> $n$|$(x_1 - x_2)$?

Giving an example, such as $n=6$ or such would better help me understand the answer. I kind of figured it out for $n=5$, however I am having difficulty understanding how to do it for any other value.

Thanks you

Comment: It cannot be "proved" if $\sim$ is not defined. Do you mean: how to prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation if $\sim$ is defined by: $x\sim y\iff n|x-y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For equivalence relations, you have to prove that it is RST - reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

In addition, it may help to consider modulo arithmetic:

$${n\, | \,x_1-x_2} \iff {x_1 \equiv x_2 \pmod n}$$

Now you should be able to solve this.

EDIT: Proof for transitivity at request. (Note that I've used $R$ to refer to the relation - personal preference)

Transitive:

$$aRb \iff n\, | \,a-b \iff {a \equiv b \pmod n}$$

$$bRc \iff n\, | \,b-c \iff {b \equiv c \pmod n}$$

$\iff a \equiv b \equiv c\pmod n$

$\iff a \equiv c\pmod n$

$\iff n\, | \,a-c$

$\iff aRc$

$\implies$ Transitive.

Comment: So, for example,i would have to prove that if  n|(x1 - x2) and n|(x2 - x3), then n|(x1 - x3) for transitive? would that be the proper way to find transitive? just trying to make sure I know how to do it properly

Comment: Edit done above.

Comment: @QuestionAsker Yes, that's the proper way to prove transitivity.